# Vite Dev Server Fails to Start

Tags: reactjs, vite

Adding vite-plugin-mix to my project's dependencies caused my vite dev server to stop working. Because I need to add rest APIs to my development server, I'm using vite-plugin-mix. So far, the only solution I have tried is updating my node version to v18.6 to ensure Vite compatibility.   Below I have included the output from npm run dev, and the contents of package.json and vite.config.js for the community's review.

```
**Terminal Output**


> vite-project@0.0.0 dev
> vite

failed to load config from /Users/name/mcsp/10-week/vite-project/vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
TypeError: mix is not a function
    at file:///Users/name/mcsp/10-week/vite-project/vite.config.js.timestamp-1683393633808-70a3d4c91bf2b.mjs:8:5
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)



**Package.json**

{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "vite-plugin-mix": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "pg": "^8.10.0",
    "vite": "^4.3.2"
  }
}

**vite.config.js**
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import mix from "vite-plugin-mix";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    mix({
      handler: "./api.js",
    }),
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue with `vite-plugin-mix`. Refer [this](https://github.com/egoist/vite-plugin-mix/issues/33#issuecomment-1255778587) for a quick workaround.

Copying here for reference:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import mix$ from 'vite-plugin-mix'

const mix = mix$.default ?? mix$

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    mix({
      handler: './api.js'
    })
  ]
})
```

But even with the fix, I don't think that plugin works with Vite 4. It hasn't been updated in a long time.

Comment: Indeed, this turned out to be the solution. I appreciate the assistance provided.